# 2D easy view animation

Tags: android

Is there a library for quickly animating views (for example let buttons enter from one side of the screen), without having to install complete frameworks?
I gave a look at **tween engine** but as far as I know it can be used only with libgdx, that asks a complete reorganization of the code. I am looking for something not too powerful, but to "install and use".

Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html ?

Comment: I think that it is from Android 3.0 on, right? Is there something for older Androids?

Comment: http://nineoldandroids.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary

"Android provides two mechanisms that you can use to create simple animations: tweened animation, in which you tell Android to perform a series of simple transformations (position, size, rotation, and so on) to the content of a View; and frame-by-frame animation, which loads a series of Drawable resources one after the other. Both animation types can be used in any View object to provide simple rotating timers, activity icons, and other useful UI elements. Tweened animation is handled by this package (android.view.animation); frame-by-frame animation is handled by the AnimationDrawable class."

android.view.animation has been available since API Level 1.